# IONIC Radio Button CSS styling Circle on all Devices

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image]

I have a group of Ionic Radio button that is appearing as checkboxes on mobile. I am trying to make it like a circle using css but it is not working I need on all screens circled radio buttons. attaching reference image please have a look

[reference site](https://jsfiddle.net/sreekanthjayan/0d9vj86k/)

```
<ion-list name="test" radio-group [(ngModel)]="ionic-radio">
   <ion-item>
      <ion-radio class="radio radio-inline radio-gray" value="3" checked></ion-radio>
      <ion-radio value="2"></ion-radio>
      <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>                           
</ion-list>
```

CSS

[used from reference site](https://jsfiddle.net/sreekanthjayan/0d9vj86k/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer here

[Get the os mode type](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/)

and add mode attribute as needed
no css no nothing easy steps..

```
<ion-radio mode="md"  value="1"></ion-radio>
```